# Python get all files from a directory Error

Tags: python, file

I have a folder which contains 22 files of .sgm format. I want to read all files. The input on command line argument that I will pass will look like

`/usr/local/pub/tmh/Reuters/*.sgm`

So this should read all the  sgm format files from the folder.

The code using python 3.4.2 that I wrote is

```
allfiles=(glob.glob(sys.argv[1]))
print(allfiles)
```

Now all i get is 1 file  `/usr/local/pub/tmh/Reuters/reut2-000.sgm`. The rest are not picked up by the glob. Also I tried to print the argument  which should print this `/usr/local/pub/tmh/Reuters/*.sgm` but it prints `/usr/local/pub/tmh/Reuters/reut2-000.sgm`(which is the first file in the folder)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your *shell* is expanding the glob for you, so you are really passing *all files* to your script as separate arguments, then looking just at the first one.

So rather than passing in `/usr/local/pub/tmh/Reuters/*.sgm` to your script, the shell passes in `/usr/local/pub/tmh/Reuters/reut2-000.sgm /usr/local/pub/tmh/Reuters/reut2-001.sgm /usr/local/pub/tmh/Reuters/reut2-002.sgm`, etc.

Either *quote* the glob or the argument, or just read all files from `sys.argv[1:]`.

Quoting the argument:

```
python yourscript.py "/usr/local/pub/tmh/Reuters/*.sgm"
```

or leaving glob expansion to the shell:

```
allfiles = sys.argv[1:]
print(allfiles)
```